# Struct vs enum lifetime differences

Tags: rust, lifetime

Why does this work

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo<'a,'b> {
    s : &'a str,
    n : &'b i32
}
#[test]
fn test_struct() {
    let f = Foo { s : &"bar" , n : &17 };
    println!("{:?}",f);
}
```

but this doesn't

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Bar<'a,'b> {
    Baz ( &'a str),
    Fub ( &'b i32)
}
#[test]
fn test_struct() {
    let b = Bar::Baz(&"Foo");
    let c = Bar::Fub(&17);
    println!("{:?} {:?}",b,c);
}
```

The error is (part of a bigger file so ignore line numbers)

```
src\lib.rs:176:27: 176:29 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src\lib.rs:176         let c = Bar::Fub(&17);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

To me it seems like `let c = Bar::Fub(&17)`, the 17 lasts the same life time as the previous line where `"Foo"` is created on the stack. If I modify it slightly and do

```
let h = &17;
let c = Bar::Fub(&h);
```

In which case it's completely clear that h lasts longer than Bar::Fub(). SoI'm not sure how I can can get this to work.

This is a follow up to [Lifetime parameters for an enum within a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785915/lifetime-parameters-for-an-enum-within-a-struct)

Comment: `"Foo"` doesn't actually live on the stack, unlike `17`. `"Foo"` is `&'static str`, so it does live longer than `17`.

Comment: I think this is the actual answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me it seems like let c = Bar::Fub(&17), the 17 lasts the same life time as the previous line where "Foo" is created on the stack

A string literal always has `'static` lifetime and will therefor always live long enough.

I think the issue is that you are hitting is the fact that an enum expression is actually somewhat of a a function call. Somewhat meaning that the lifetime of the argument is ignored in the computation of the Enum's lifetime. The Enum's lifetime apparently is marginally larger, as if you wrote:

```
let c: Bar;
let x = &17;
c = Bar::Fub(x);
```

which is already addressed in [Scope of addresses: Does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049194/scope-of-addresses-does-not-live-long-enough)

> In which case it's completely clear that h lasts longer than Bar::Fub().

Yes, the lifetimes are clear here, and it [works in the Playpen](http://is.gd/KSee0P):

```
let x = &17;
let c = Bar::Fub(x);
```

so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I missed the 'static' scope for the string. But yes once I realised that, the rest is obvious; though a little annoying. I guess I have to store everything in Bar as values rather than references just to be consistent.